# Java Offline GPS Tracker for Android

Tags: java, android, gps, p2p

I have a very clear of the mobile app i'm currently developing right now.

Look at [image: this picture guys!]

There are 3 areas.

1. Server
2. Group A
3. Group B

Okay here is the case. Imagine that User from Group A and B are using the -1- similar App
Called, "**OurApp**". With the help of that App. They could get the following scenarios:

**User from Group A** could detect the existence of the **User from Group B**.
**Using Wifi only**. They could detect one to another. But take note, that **User
from Group B has no Internet connection** at all.

And also, **User from Group A** want to know where the **User from Group B** is currently located at.

I'm thinking that **this is possible, yes.**
But only if the device of **User Group B could have** a similar like **GPS Tracker**.

But my question here is, "**Could Android devices nowadays do that without internet connection**?" And **from where did the user A know the user B through GPS location**?

My curiousity send me into a discussion with the other java programmers. They said, 
"Yes, it's possible for User Group B send his location to User Group A, when they're connected each other and IF only User A is connected to the server who has the main GPS Server."

And, so for now... I'm curious. What's the clue for this case,
does anyone have ever found the similar case like this without enabling data / internet connectivity on their mobile devices?

-cmiiw-

Comment: `Could Android devices nowadays do that without internet connection` ---> `NO`

Comment: unfortunately I found the way of making offline gps without internet. 
The answer is when the connected pair is connected to the gps (map) server. Then the other pair connected could get the same access. :D 

-networking games-

Comment: hi @Kedarnath, ... are you still there? I think i need a little bit help here regarding the GPS Location,... how to make it shown on the map (embedded) that I have....

Comment: [How to plot lat-lon on google map?](https://www.google.co.in/search?output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Android%2BHow+to+plot++lat-lon+on+google+map+%3F&btnG=)